# Using Spring Query Methods JPA to efficiently query DB without multiple SELECT statements

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity that has simple String columns as well as many ElementCollections (List and Map). I noticed looking at my postgres logs that PostGres when querying for this entity is doing a bunch of SELECT queries consecutively to get all the ElementCollections.

For efficiency, I would imagine doing one SELECT query with some inner JOINs might be better to avoid all of the individual SELECT queries. Is there a way to do that without writing a very verbose select query manually with all the INNER JOINs?

I have been looking around FetchTypes and Spring QueryData language, and DTO Projection but I imagine there might be a more straightforward way. The benefit I had been taking for granted is by explictly doing the JOINs if I add a new field then I will have to keep updating my query and if Spring is generating queries for me, then I wouldn't have to do anything.

```
// Person.java

@Entity
public Person {

    @Id
    long personId;

    @Column
    String firstName;

    @Column
    String lastName;

    @ElementCollections
    Set<String> someField;

    @ElementCollections
    Map<String, String> otherField;

    @ElementCollections
    Set<String> anotherField;

    @ElementCollections
    Map<String, String> yetAnotherField;
}
```

What is happening right now is

```
SELECT firstName, lastName FROM Person WHERE personId=$1
SELECT someField FROM Person_SomeField WHERE someField.personId=$1
SELECT otherField.key otherField.value FROM Person_OtherField WHERE otherField.personId=$1
```

And this continues for all of the ElementCollections tables which leads to a lot of queries.

Answer (score 0):

Change your annotation to `@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`.

It sounds like those fields are being lazily loaded (Hibernate is waiting until they are accessed to load them) which results in the N+1 queries you are seeing. `LAZY` loading is the default behavior for this type of member, which makes sense because loading it is not cheap. However, if you always want these members loaded, setting it to `EAGER` can make sense. Setting the fetch to `EAGER` will force Hibernate to load them along with the entity itself. This is the documentation for the `fetch` option on `@ElementCollection`:

> (Optional) Whether the collection should be lazily loaded or must be
>   eagerly fetched. The EAGER strategy is a requirement on the
>   persistence provider runtime that the collection elements must be
>   eagerly fetched. The LAZY strategy is a hint to the persistence
>   provider runtime.